# Why do non-linear activation functions that produce values larger than 1 or smaller than 0 work?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, activation-functions, relu, cross-entropy

Why do non-linear activation functions that produce values larger than 1 or smaller than 0 work?

My understanding is that neurons can only produce values between 0 and 1, and that this assumption can be used in things like cross-entropy. Are my assumptions just completely wrong?

Is there any reference that explains this?

Comment: [This discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46659525/712995) might be helpful

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn't they work?

Each neuron's output is equal to a function over the sum of all its weights multiplied by their corresponding neurons. If that function is the [Sigmoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function) function, then the output is squashed from $[0,1]$. If the entire layer uses a [SoftMax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function) function, then the output of all neurons is squashed from $[0,1]$ and their sum equals 1. In other others, they represent a set of probabilities, where you can then use [cross-entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy) to optimize their values (cross-entropy measures the difference between two probability distributions).

[ReLU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)) and [ELU](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.07289) are simply other types of functions, whose output is not limited to the range $[0, 1]$. They are differentiable, like other activation functions, and so they can be used in any neural network.

Comment: I think the OP was confused about the fact that the cross-entropy _may_ require a probability vector as input, so, by using activation functions that do not have values in the range $[0, 1]$, the output of the neural network may not be a probability vector. You partially address this by mentioning the softmax, but I think this answer could definitely be improved by explaining more in detail the cross-entropy, and it's relation to the softmax and other activation functions of the hidden neurons.

Answer (score 1):

Christopher Olah's [blog post](http://colah.github.io/posts/2014-03-NN-Manifolds-Topology/) describes it better that I ever could.
Basically, most data we come across can't be separated with a single line, but with some kind of curve. Non-linearities allow us to distort the input space in ways that make the data linearly separable, making classification more accuarate.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. This answers another question, which is "Why do we need non-linearities?". Please, read the **actual** question again.